# Get the tab number in the View. Android

Tags: android, android-intent, view, tabs, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs in the action bar. My TabListener class implements the ActionBar.TabListener to create the new TabFragment.

In the TabFragment Class (which extends Fragment), in the method "OnCreateView" I inflate a costum View.

The point is that I want to use the same View for each tab just changing a word. 
The View just write "this is the tab X" in the center of the screen  but i want the X change depending of which tab is selected. I think there is two options to do what I want but I don't find how to do either of them.

- In "MyView" class, get the tab number which is selected.
- Send a intent from the fragment class to the View with an extra saying which tab is, and read that extra in the intent (don't know how can i do it because the View hasn't got a Bundle)

Just to say that there is only one activity on the application.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a static variable

```
public static int tabNo;
      // OR
public static String tabName;
```

On selection of tab refer this static variable and change its name/no

and in your fragement or in activity change text of textView

```
textView.setText("This is tab :"+tabName");
```

Comment: This is absolutely great! 
Thank you so much ^^